# why Borel's computation implies Beilinson-Soulé?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, motives

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and $DM(k)_{\mathrm{Q}}$ Voevodsky's category of motives over $k$ with rational coefficients. The Beilinson-Soulé conjecture says
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{DM(k)_{\mathrm{Q}}}(M(X), \mathbb{Q}(p)[q])=0 \quad \quad (\ast)
$$
whenever $p>0$ and $q\leq 0$. Here $M$ denotes the functor from smooth variteties over $k$ to $DM(k)_{\mathrm{Q}}$.

For $X=Spec(k)$, where $k$ is a number field, this follows from Borel's computation of the rank of K-theory. Why?

I know that the rough answer is: Hom's in Voevodsky's category are given by higher Chow groups, which are isomorphic to (graded pieces) of $K$-theory, but can anybody give a precise explanation (in particular, with the indices...). Is is true, for instance, that there is only one graded piece for the Adams operations on $K_i(k) \otimes_{\mathrm{Z}} \mathrm{Q}$?

Answer (score 12):

The Beilinson-Soulé conjecture is not necessarily something about motives. Before Voevodsky's definition of the derived category of motives, the Beilinson-Soulé conjecture was formulated as a question about Adams eigenspaces of K-theory. Of course, people were expecting/anticipating the existence of a (derived) category of motives and were using the graded pieces of the $\gamma$-filtration as replacements for motivic cohomology groups.

The translation between the various forms the Beilinson-Soulé conjecture can take is given by the identifications
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{DM(k)_{\mathbb{Q}}}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}(p)[q])\cong H^p_{\operatorname{Nis}}(\operatorname{Spec}k,\mathbb{Q}(q))\cong CH^q(\operatorname{Spec}k,2q-p)_{\mathbb{Q}}\cong K_{2q-p}(k)^{(q)}_{\mathbb{Q}}.
$$

The first identification is close to the definition of motivic cohomology. The second identification is Voevodsky's theorem on identification of motivic cohomology with Bloch's higher Chow groups ([paper link here](http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2002/7/351.full.pdf)), and the last identification is due to Bloch (S. Bloch. Algebraic cycles and algebraic K-theory. Adv. Math. 61, 1986).
Some more details can also be found in the [lecture notes on motivic cohomology](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/cmi/library/MotivicCohomologyold.pdf) by Mazza, Voevodsky and Weibel.
Eventually, I think the reason for these identifications being true is that motivic cohomology is defined as the cohomology of the sheaf of Bloch's cycle complexes, and these have a suitable fibrancy property. That all of this works out is the mystery hidden in the proof details.

Anyway, the K-theoretic formulation of the Beilinson-Soulé conjecture is a consequence of Borel's computation of the ranks of the rational K-groups plus of course the identification of the weights. The identification of weights can be done using the Beilinson-regulator to Deligne cohomology. A list of the right weights and some explanation can be found in [this MO-question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52702/adams-graded-parts-of-rational-k-theory-of-a-number-field) Some more details on how to get the weights can be found in [this MO-question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65635/rationalised-k-theory-of-number-fields/65650)